# Foxit reader portable do not remember the configuration?

Tags: wine, pdf

I've installed a portable `Foxit` reader using wine. Everything is fine except the program do not remember any configurations I've set up.

For example, I configured the default noting color to green, but every time I start the program, the configuration is lost.

Others like shortcuts or something also lost.

The wine is 1.62 and `Foxit` reader is 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Why you use wine instead you can just use foxit native in Ubuntu!

#### Install Foxit Reader 1.1 on 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04:

```
wget http://cdn02.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/linux/1.x/1.1/enu/FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb
```

#### Install Foxit Reader 1.1 on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get update

wget http://cdn02.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/linux/1.x/1.1/enu/FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb
```

[source and more information](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-foxit-reader-1-1-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivative-systems/)

Comment: I want to highlight, the foxit native do not support this feather.

Comment: Use Okular instead, it's much times better than foxit

Comment: I've used Okular, which is not very satisfactory. The highlighting seems cannot stored in the pdf files(? long time ago, now I'm not sure).

Comment: it's stored, I use it frequently

Comment: In this link: https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html . It says each time you need to save a copy to overwrite the original pdf files, this is a little bit annoying. As it said, okular using proppler rendering package, which is also used in evince and qpdfview. Up to now, I still think using wine is the best choice.